# Latex: reference.bib shows reference number without reference text

Tags: reference, latex, bibliography

my reference.bib page shows the last reference in the list [150] with no reference in text. Notice, there is no duplication in citation and in reference.bib since I removed all duplications in reference page and in chapters. Please help me. I uses \bibliography{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} as my grad school requirement

I attached the reference page:

[image]

reference page:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x13qtAEISvwBOw5kmN9CZ3D4lHa5gXN9/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are errors in your document, there is no point at looking at the output (see red marker at the top right). After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily sensible output.

The log file will tell you about each and every error. Don't ignore error messages - fix them!

There are two major problems in your .bib file:

- the syntax `\url={...}` is just wrong. It should be `\url{...}`. This occurrences  many times
- `&` is a special character for latex. You must escape it if you want to use it in normal text:

```
@article{Hasan,
author = {Takabi, Hassan and Joshi, James and Ahn, Gail-Joon},
year = {2011},
month = {01},
pages = {24 - 31},
title = {Security and Privacy Challenges in Cloud Computing Environments},
volume = {8},
journal = {Security \& Privacy, IEEE},
doi = {10.1109/MSP.2010.186}
}
```